# Read values from XML with ChildNodes with namespaces

Tags: xml, delphi, dom, delphi-xe2

I have 2 XML files, first this one which works just fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns3:ConsultarSituacaoLoteRpsResposta xmlns:ns2="http://www.ginfes.com.br/tipos_v03.xsd" xmlns:ns3="http://www.ginfes.com.br/servico_consultar_situacao_lote_rps_resposta_v03.xsd">
  <ListaMensagemRetorno>
    <ns2:MensagemRetorno>
      <ns2:Codigo>E172</ns2:Codigo>
    </ns2:MensagemRetorno>
  </ListaMensagemRetorno>
</ns3:ConsultarSituacaoLoteRpsResposta>
```

The code I'm using to read it is something like this:

```
MyNode := Doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.First.ChildNodes.FindNode('MensagemRetorno');
MyValue := MyNode.ChildValues['Codigo'];
```

The problem is that I have a second XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ConsultarSituacaoLoteRpsResposta xmlns="http://www.issnetonline.com.br/webserviceabrasf/vsd/servico_consultar_situacao_lote_rps_resposta.xsd">
  <ListaMensagemRetorno>
    <MensagemRetorno>
        <Codigo xmlns="http://www.issnetonline.com.br/webserviceabrasf/vsd/tipos_complexos.xsd">E156</Codigo>
    </MensagemRetorno>
  </ListaMensagemRetorno>
</ConsultarSituacaoLoteRpsResposta>
```

Notice that this XML have a namespace in the "Codigo" node, so my code doesn't find this node.

The only way I found to read the "Codigo" value from this second XML was like this:

```
for I := 0 to MyNode.ChildNodes.Count -1 do
begin
  ChildNode := RetornoNode.ChildNodes[I];
  if ChildNode.NodeName = 'Codigo' then
    Codigo := ChildNode.NodeValue;
end;
```

But I think that there should be a better way to do this, as I still didn't understand why the first code doesn't work with the second XML.

Anyone could please clarify it for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This it seems a limitation of the [`ChildValues`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLIntf.IXMLNode.ChildValues) property

You can use one of these alternatives to return the value

```
 MyNode := Doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.First.ChildNodes.FindNode('MensagemRetorno');
 MyValue :=MyNode.ChildNodes.First.Text;
```

or using the overloaded version of the [`FindNode`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/XMLIntf.IXMLNodeList.FindNode) method

```
 MyNode := Doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.First.ChildNodes.FindNode('MensagemRetorno');
 MyValue:= MyNode.ChildNodes.FindNode('Codigo','http://www.issnetonline.com.br/webserviceabrasf/vsd/tipos_complexos.xsd').Text;
```